# for loop in lambda makes it ambiguous

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, lambda, eclipse-jdt

When i use a loop in a lambda that could be used as Consumer or Function it becomes ambiguous. This happens when the loop is the last statement.

I already know that i can renaming one of the methods will workaround the problem, but i would like to know why this is happening.

Here is a minimal example:

```
public class Test {
    public static class A{
        public void a(Consumer<Object> task){
        }

        public <R> R a(Function<Object, R> task){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();

        //okay
        a.a(obj -> {
        });

        //not okay: 
        //"The method a(Consumer<Object>) is ambiguous for the type Test.A"
        a.a(obj -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            }
        });

        //okay
        a.a(obj -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            }
            {}
        });
    }
}
```

edit:

reported the bug at eclipse

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499789

Comment: I can't reproduce that with javac 1.8.0_51 (and with Eclipse Neon). This compiles fine. What version of javac are you using?

Comment: Hm. If i compile this via javac in commandline there is no error.
In Eclipse the error remains. I use Eclipse Neon aswell with jdk1.8.0_92 with JDT 3.12.0.v20160606-1100

Comment: I have Eclipse Neon too and the error disappears if you add `;` right after the `for` loop. No idea why it appears in the first place though.

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan As i already described the loop must not be the last statement, so `;` works fine aswell. Maybe a another bug in Eclipse?

Comment: I have a theory: maybe with the loop being the last statement Eclipse is unable to tell if the lambda returns something or not, thus making it impossible to tell the difference between both `a()` methods in your class. It does look like a compiler bug, though.

Comment: The names you have chosen for the parameters are very confusing. You use the name `task` to refer to both the `Consumer<Object>` and also the `Object` instance.

Comment: changed the instance object names for less confusion